# create multithreaded java ee

Tags: java, multithreading, glassfish

Is it possible to create a multithreaded Java EE Glassfish container?

My intention is to create an application where users can capture data launch a social network, then each user would launch a new thread with the parameters he wants to retrieve information from the social network.
all these threads would be limited in number to avoid memory server.

As I can create multiple threads in java ee and that these once the user exits the application to remain running in the background until the user closes them?

One solution may be the job of glassfish?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow... your question is by far to broad... you need to take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/tour and come back later

Comment: thanks for the tips, you note that I am new to stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty broad, but in general I understand you need to execute a thread for each user, which runs in background even when user stops using the application (logs out), does some repetitive task, and is terminated by user when required.

First, I would point out that this can be accomplished in cleaner way using timer service - you can schedule a periodical background job, which will do everyting you need. It can read the list of user and their tasks, perform them at a given interval. Then, a user may request to cance their tasks - they will remove their task from the list.

In this way, the number of users having the background task running would not be limited. They also can run sequentially in a single thread, but you may tweak that, see the rest of my answer.

More into on shceduling a timer in Java EE tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/ejb-basicexamples004.htm.

In case you really need a separate thread per user, there are several ways how to execute a thread separately from the request-handling thread. You might use asynchronous EJB method invocation, using `@Asynchronous` annotation. You may also inject `ManagedExecutorService` and use it to execute a `Runnable` asynchrnously using `submit` method. In both ways, you would not loose context and dependency injection will continue to work.

See more details about asynchronous eecution in Java EE tutorial about [Concurrency utilities](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/concurrency-utilities.htm#GKJIQ8)

You may also execute runnables asynchronously from a timer, but you may not need that, if you execute only a single task from within a timer handler, as timer handler will be executed when timer triggers in a new thread, if the previous handler did not complete yet.

Comment: thanks for your reply. By using scheduling it is one of the first choices that went through my head, but I have a problem, each of the "threads" have to establish a permanent coneion http with an external service. It is not something periodic and repetitive, but something permanent.
I think I'll find the solution using the Concurrency Utilities. Thank you very much for the URL.
You can not find too many examples of using Concurrency Utilities.